My xv6's allocproc(void) gives trash values to my new process. What is the problem?
I'm doing my OperationSystem project which is to make Mlfq,Priority + Moq policy scheduler.
But while I'm doing, my allocproc() function gives me very strange value.
I didn't edited anything but only just five lines, which was inevitable.
Then, even when xv6 is booting and calls userinit() and fork(), their process values are very strange.
static struct proc*
allocproc(void)
{
  struct proc *p;
  char *sp;

  acquire(&ptable.lock);

  for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++)
    if(p->state == UNUSED)
      goto found;

  release(&ptable.lock);
  return 0;

found:
  p->state = EMBRYO;
  p->pid = nextpid++;

  //project02
  p->level = 0;
  p->priority = 0;
  p->proc_tick = 0;
  p->tick_limit = 2;
  p->l3_repeat = 0;

  release(&ptable.lock);

  // Allocate kernel stack.
  if((p->kstack = kalloc()) == 0){
    p->state = UNUSED;
    return 0;
  }
  sp = p->kstack + KSTACKSIZE;

  // Leave room for trap frame.
  sp -= sizeof *p->tf;
  p->tf = (struct trapframe*)sp;

  // Set up new context to start executing at forkret,
  // which returns to trapret.
  sp -= 4;
  *(uint*)sp = (uint)trapret;

  sp -= sizeof *p->context;
  p->context = (struct context*)sp;
  memset(p->context, 0, sizeof *p->context);
  p->context->eip = (uint)forkret;

  return p;
}

Booting from Hard Disk..xv6...
cpu0: starting 0
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
sb: size 1000 nblocks 941 ninodes 200 nlog 30 logstart 2 inodestart 32 bmap start 58
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
init: starting sh
debugging : Inside alloc : Find next array space
debugging : after fork at init.c
dedebugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
bugging : after fork at init.c
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720
debugging : pid : 0,  level:549543,  priority:-2146398720,  tick:549552,  limit:-2146398720

Even though at the top of proc.c, there is int nexpid=1;, the very first process got the pid 0.
I've checked other functions and header files, it seems like there is no problem.
And also i excuted my xv6 not only in the Vscode Remote Explorer(docker) but also in Ubuntu termial(docker), and the result was same.

How do you launch the os? From which repo/commit did you start? What function generates the debugging messages?
